# Apache2 No Listening Sockets, unable to open logs while trying to configure virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, socket, namevirtualhost

I'm trying to set up multiple domains with virtual hosts in Apache2. I'm currently getting a "Could not connect" error when I try to browse to my site, and whenever I try to restart Apache2, I get an error about "no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs".

Originally, after configuring apache2.conf and my /apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com, I was getting a 500 server error and a warn from apache2 that "NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts". Then I commented out an extra (I think) NameVirtualHost *:80 in the ports.conf file, and now the cannot connect and no sockets error.

Here's what's at the bottom of my apache2.conf:

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80
#<VirtualHost *:80>                                                            

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfModule>
```

And my /apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com:

```
          # domain: domain1.com
          # public: /home/demo/public_html/domain1.com/

<VirtualHost *:80>

 # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
 ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com
 ServerName  domain1.com
 ServerAlias domain1.com


 # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
 DirectoryIndex index.html
 DocumentRoot /home/demo/public_html/domain1.com/public


 # Custom log file locations
 LogLevel warn
 ErrorLog  /home/demo/public_html/domain1.com/log/error.log
 CustomLog /home/demo/public_html/domain1.com/log/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And finally, my ports.conf:

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80                                                            
#Listen 80                                                                     

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change      
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl    
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>                                                   
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not      
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.                                         
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

I appreciate any insight that can be offered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you've commented out the `Listen 80` line, so Apache isn't listening on the normal `http` port.

You're other `Listen` directives are inside `IfModule` blocks, so if those modules aren't present, you have effectively configured Apache to not listen on any ports, which may be the source of your error.

Try uncommenting the line:

```
Listen 80
```

In your ports.conf.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Now I'm getting a 500 server error, and not just that terrifying no connection. I'll go bang on it a bit more, try and fix that. Again, thanks.

Comment: ...and up and fixed entirely.